# Macbook Pro late 2011 + Windows 10+ High Sierra

Tags: bootcamp, windows, high-sierra

I'm struggling for two days now trying to install Windows 10 on my Macbook Pro  Can anybody help me out? I tried several methods, and none is working for me.

MacBook Pro 2011 Late
High Sierra
No CD Drive
SSD + HDD (SSD main Drive running osx + hdd storage switched with cd drive)
Modified Bootcamp to use USB Stick

Windows 10 should be installed at the main drive but if its easier to install Windows on my HDD (which I'm only using for storage) I'll take that.
But I guess I tried that as well with the same result.

I tried several methods like :
http://osxdaily.com/2015/06/05/copy-iso-to-usb-drive-mac-os-x-command/
...
I can't find the other links anymore

Clean install without Bootcamp using unetbootin

The final result is always the same when I try to install Windows, I'm always stuck at the step where I have to choose the installation disk, it always says "windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk is of the gpt partition style" or no volume at this drive to install Windows. When I choose to delete the formatted disk it starts the installation, breaks up after a few % and says can't fulfill the next installation step.

Comment: Your question is missing various critical information.What methods have you tried? Are you attempting to install Windows 10 on the same drive as macOS, or the other one? Please edit your question to add relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to successfully install Windows 10 on my Late 2008 MacBook running macOS Sierra. I created a bootable Windows 10 USB key on another PC and performed a normal install on my MacBook.

As per official guidelines, Late 2008 MacBook does not support installing versions of Windows later than Windows 7 using Boot Camp. But I was able to find a workaround, thereby doing a **normal PC installation**.

The installer must be created on a pen-drive and not on a external hard-disk as it can create troubles.

I first created a Windows partition on macOS by resizing, plugged in the bootable pen-drive, restarted my MacBook, pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> key till the boot device selection screen appeared. Then I performed a normal Windows installation.

Windows can overwrite the boot loader which can be repaired with the recovery partition.

Comment: I dont get all the points properly, can u write it down like a step by step guide. because i totally fucked up my ssd after the last tries and was missign 50gb of disk space and had to clean the disk and make a fresh set up

Comment: @Kirk K.: Lack of details runs both ways. You question is sorrowfully lacking details. It would be helpful to include the output from `diskutil list`, `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0` and `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`. You will need to boot to macOS recovery mode to run the `gpt` and `fdisk` commands. Also, how much space do you what to allocate to Windows?

Comment: I don't remember the whole process but it was no very easy.

You would need a windows machine, to do a bootable windows installation pen can be hardly on macOs. First make the WinInstall pen and test it restarting the windows computer. If it works, let's go to work with the mac.

If the macOS stills working, load the OS and open the Disk Manager App, resize your original partition to let empty space for the windows installation

Comment: After the resizing, power off the machine, insert the Windows install pen drive, start it pressing "alt" key till the boot loader, and boot from the stick.

Comment: Ive got a Windows PC available today, how do i create a Windows install pen?

Comment: So I simply have to add a partition to my mac drive, put that usb stick in and while start, pressing alt key, how do i kill the boot loader? than normally install windows on the new partition and et  voila its installed? but how do i kill the boot loader and how to i fix it afterwards?

Comment: Best Option to make the install pen is from the Microsoft tool.and the boot loader allows to boot from a pen (if the Mac don't find it try to make it again, I t can be difficult) and when starting to boot from all bootable partitions, inclusive the macOS recovery partition (so was it on my macbook late 2008)

Comment: and a tip; turn off the "fast startup" option on windows, I.had problem with the windows system image after updating.

Comment: Actually holding down just the "Alt" key should be sufficient to see boot device selection. I don't know where the "Alt-r" idea came from.